# Reading the 7th and 8th number to identify region in country

Tags: c

I'm new to C Programming and trying to make a program like this.

```
char name[20];
int icNumber;

printf("Enter your name\n");
scanf("%s",&name);

printf("Enter your IC Number\n");
scanf("%d",&icNumber);
```

Whenever I enter the IC number, I want the program to read the 7th and 8th number to identify which region does the person belong to.
For example.

```
**Name: Mohamad**
**IC Number: 761010015667**
```

The program then identifies the 7th and 8th number and it will give out this answer.

```
**Your region number is 01. You live in Johor.**
```

How do I do this? I would be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: 1) Insure all compiler warnings are enabled.  I'd expect `scanf("%s",&name);` to warn.  2) Post a [MCVE]

Comment: Are IC numbers always the same length? Then you can use `(icNumber / 1000) % 100`. Otherwise you would be better of using a string for the IC Number and using icNumber[7] to access the 7th digit.

Comment: The first chapters of your C programming book will mention the range of `int`. On 32 bit systems it can only hold values up to 2^31 -1, that is 2.14 billion.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  For both of the posted calls to `scanf()`, the only valid returned value would be 1   2) when using the '%s' or '%[..]' input format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  Because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  When using the '%d' specifier, the result is a 'int', not a string of digits.  Suggest using '%14s' for a char array of 15